# How to stop emacs server

Tags: emacs

I started a Emacs in my terminal, and then started running Emacs server inside it by `M-x server-start`. Now I would like to cancel running the Emacs server without exiting the Emacs process. There seems to be no command for that. How can i do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The command to do that from inside emacs is

```
M-x server-mode
```

The first time you run it, it'll restart the server it's running. The second time, it'll stop the server.

To make sure that you're stopping the server, pass a non-positive prefix argument: `M-0 M-x server-mode RET`

Comment: Thanks. what is the difference between it and M-x server-start for starting the server?

Comment: I was wrong at first; it doesn't start the server if it isn't running already, it just restarts it if it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can stop the server by running `server-force-delete`, e.g. interactively by doing `M-x server-force-delete`.

Comment: In my attempts to use this, it just deletes the socket file that the server is using to accept connections from clients, but the server process continues running.